# Efficient alternative for calculating sum of number of prime divisors (not distinct) of numbers till num

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, runtime-error, primes

A number is said to have `n` prime divisors if it can factored into `n` prime numbers (not necessarily distinct).
E.g.:

```
12 = 2*2*3 ---> 12 has 3 prime divisors
```

Given numbers `a` and `b` we have to find the number of such prime divisors of `a!`/`b!`(`a>=b`). Hence I decided to do the following way:

```
long long pre[5000001];

long long solve(int num)
{
    if(!num)
        return 0;
    if(pre[num] || num==1)
        return pre[num];
    int num1=num;
    if(num1%2==0)
    {
        int cnt=0;
        while(num1%2==0)
        {
            num1/=2;
            cnt++;
        }
        pre[num] = solve(num-1) + (solve(num1)-solve(num1-1)) + cnt;
        return pre[num];
    }

    for(int i=3;i<=(int)(sqrt(num1))+1;++i)
    {
        if(num1%i==0)
        {
            int cnt=0;
            while(num1%i==0)
            {
                cnt++;
                num1/=i;
            }
            pre[num] = solve(num-1) + (solve(num1)-solve(num1-1)) + cnt;
            return pre[num];
        }
    }
    if(num>1)
    {
        pre[num]=1 + solve(num-1);
        return pre[num];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    pre[1]=0;
    while(t--)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        long long ans = solve(a)-solve(b);
        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My approach was to basically to calculate the number of prime divisors and store them because the limit for `a` and `b` was `<=5000000`. `pre[num]` gives the sum of number of prime divisors of all numbers `<=num`. But it results in run-time error for larger inputs such as `a=5000000 b=4999995`. Is there any better way to do this or the present approach can be tweaked for a better solution?

Comment: @Jarod42....no since I mentioned `pre[num]` gives the `sum` of number of prime divisors till `num`. You can tell `ans = f(b+1)...+f(a)` where `f(num)` gives number of prime divisors of `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You reach your limit of recursion.

To fix your problem, your may build your array from 0 to `a` first:

```
int main()
{
    int max_a = 0;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    pre[1] = 0;
    while(t--)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;

        for (int i = max_a; i < a; ++i) {
            solve(i); // memoization until `a` max recursion is limited to 1 :)
        }
        max_a = std::max(max_a, a);
        long long ans = solve(a) - solve(b);
        std::cout << ans << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially thought this was the case, however I thought c++ didn't have a recursion limit. See [Does C++ limit recursion depth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630054/does-c-limit-recursion-depth).

Comment: You were correct @Jarod42 . But this time my solution was judged `time limit exceeded` although the `run-time error` message was gone. Any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your array can be `constexpr` on the principle.You may so generate the array once in other file, and hardcode it directly in main. (I failed to construct that array as `consexpr` with *"constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit; possible infinite loop?"* :( )