# Increase recursion depth

Tags: c++, linux, g++

How to increase stack/recursion depth of g++ in Linux?

Comment: Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630054/does-c-limit-recursion-depth can be useful in this case.

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks for pointing it out.  I have posted this question with an answer but mistakenly write "the following code will work" in the question itself.

Comment: @Mihai8 Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630054/does-c-limit-recursion-depth is informative.

Comment: @NamanJain OK, that looks more understandable. So your question is a duplicate of [Change stack size for a C++ application in Linux during compilation with GNU compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a header file

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

and in the main() function you need to write these lines as...

```cpp
int main(){
 rlimit R; // Unsigned integral type used for limit values.
 getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &R);
 R.rlim_cur = R.rlim_max; // Limit on stack size. 
 setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &R);
 // your code
}
```

Learn more about `<sys/resource.h>`  [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysresource.h.html).